# Can't call a method from another class in same package(JAVA)

Tags: java

i can't call a method from another class within the same package. it shows me error "cannot find symbol".
here is the code of called class

```
package demo;
import java.util.*;
public class sample
{
protected void play()
{
//some code here....
}
public String game(int num)
{
//calling play() method...
return str;
}
}
```

and here is the calling class..

```
package demo;
import java.util.*;
public class sample1
{
protected void playGame()
{
game(num);
}
}
```

I used two methods, first is creating instance of the sample class. And second is with static keyword. Both shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of a Class before you can invoke a method on it (unless the method is static).

In playGame(), try this:

```
protected void playGame()
{
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.game(num);
}
```

Comment: Or you need to extend the class sample in sample1 , and then you can call all methods of class sample in class sample1.